# Website Redesign TIps

Tags: html, css

Good Morning Everyone,

I have a new project that I will be taking on and that is redesigning an eCommerce website that has been around for a while (Since 2004). I know that the redesign will be done in html & css.

My question is, does anyone have any tips on how I should go about it? Any past experiences that you can share that have helped you?

This will be my first time taking up a project of this size so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into other eCommerce websites for inspiration (unless you really want to go creative). Also, a good new "technology" that has come about since 2004 is flexbox, which is purely css, which will make your life way easier building up the layout for the items you are selling.

Comment: FLexbox? Never heard of it, I will give it a look. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah! If it helped you out, give my comment an upvote! :)